# CMD: search IP's of devices with special MAC

Tags: windows, parsing, cmd, network-programming

I need to find IP of device or devices in local network. I only know that their MAC address should start with "xx-xx-xx-xx-". I found following script that do almost what I need:

```
@echo off
:top
:: Loop through arp table entries and look for my device's MAC address
for /f "tokens=1-5 skip=3" %%f  in ('arp -a') do (
if "%%g"=="xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx" set ip=%%f
)

if "%ip%"=="" (
    echo Discovering network...
:: Ping all IPs from 192.168.0.1 to 254
    for /L %%N in (1,1,254) do start /b ping -n 1 -w 200 192.168.0.%%N >nul
    timeout 1 >nul
    goto :top
) else (
    echo Device found found: %ip%
)
pause
```

But this script search only with full MAC and only one device. How make it search subMAC and several devices?

Comment: `...in ('arp -a^|find " 01-00-5e-") do ...`

Comment: i just tried to use that, but it didn't work. It write "can't find file 'arp -a^|find " 02-50-c2-db" (MAC, I'm looking for). Next "Discovering network..." and ping all Ip's in range again and again. But this MAC do exist in list.

Comment: oops, sorry, forgot a `'`: `...in ('arp -a^|find " 02-50-c2-db"') do ...`

Comment: correction it says  "can't find file 'arp -a|find " 02-50-c2-db" - no "^"

Comment: strange things with "find" happenings. It successfully finds "02-" or "50" strings, but it can't find "02-50". I tried "02.50", "02 50", "02:50" - no result. If string longer than 3 chars, it can't find anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following works for me:

```
@echo off
:top
:: Loop through arp table entries and look for my device's MAC address
set "ip=" 
for /f "tokens=2" %%f  in ('arp -a^|find " d4-85-64"') do set ip=%%f

if "%ip%"=="" (
    echo Discovering network...
:: Ping all IPs from 192.168.0.1 to 254
    for /L %%N in (1,1,254) do start /b ping -n 1 -w 200 192.168.0.%%N >nul
    timeout 1 >nul
    goto :top
)
echo Device found: %ip%
pause
```

Changes:
`set "ip="` to empty variable (in case, it already exists (from previous run))
removed `skip` (not needed),
set `"tokens=2"` (that's all, we need)
included `find " xx-xx-xx"` to search the desired line (with leading space for "start with") (of course I choosed a MAC existing in MY network)
moved success message out of `if` (not neccesary, but cleaner code)

Comment: It works! Thank you. Don't know why it works now, probably was strange things with tokens... Btw it returns MAC address, not IP. Probably need to type "for /f "tokens=1,2" %%f  in ..."

Comment: oh - IP. Just `"tokens=1"`. Or omit it completely ("tokens=1" is the default). More likely, your problem was `skip=3`, which ignores the first three lines